# To-infinitive usage: which sentence is correct?

Tags: grammar

which one of the following sentences is correct and why?

1. Her face was intentionally blurred in the photo to not to reveal her identity?
2. Her face was intentionally blurred in the photo not to reveal her identity?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to ELU Stack Exchange. Please note that questions are not for proofreading or "which is correct?" Please check the [help] and possibly check the sister site English Language Learners. Also, [these search results](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22to+not%22+is%3Aquestion) might be of use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither is correct.

The correct form would be:

*Her face was intentionally blurred in the photo, **so as** not to reveal her identity*.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please also tell me if the same sentence can be corrected by leaving to-infinitive intact?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. It is intact, isn't it?

Comment: Just had a close look at it and understood. Thanks again!